# amfast installation error on Ubuntu

Tags: python, amf

I tried to install amfast on Ubuntu 10.10 but when i run the setup.py i get the following after the installation runs for a little time, how do i fix this?

```
Processing dependencies for AmFast==0.5.1
Searching for uuid
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/uuid/
Download error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/uuid/
Download error: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'uuid' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for uuid
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('uuid')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm.. it looks like there was some kind of remote server problem. 
Have you tried to open http://pypi.python.org/simple/uuid/ in a browser?

(P.S. the installation works fine for me on Ubuntu 10.10)

Comment: i tried that when i was installing it about 5 hours ago and it didn't open ... but now it opens ... & the installation worked :D thanks